# Automator Run Shell Script - Wrong output

Tags: automator, rsync

I'm using Rsync for backing up a server. I thought I would make use of Automator to create easy backup-executables.
And as the server has large amounts of data I need to split the data across multple disks.

If I run this command in **Terminal**

```
/usr/local/bin/rsync -avzh --exclude="/[M-Z]*/*" --delete --progress 'root@x.x.x.x:"/mnt/raid/customers/"' "/Volumes/8TB1/Backup/customers/"
```

This works fine, it copies all customers with names that starts with A-L. M-Z gets exluded.

However, when I use **Automator** with **Run Shell Script** it copies *Everything*, nothing is excluded.
Selected shell /bin/sh or /bin/bash doesnt seem to make any difference.

I find it weird, why would this work differently running the same script?
Any takers?

Thanks,
Peter

*macOS Catalina - 10.15.3*

Comment: I'm totally guessing here @peter, is it about zsh vs bash ?

Comment: I tried a lot of different things, changing " to ' using =, not using =.... I ended up using apple script and making it run thru terminal.